# S3 Event notification to KMS_MANAGED encrypted SQS queue (in CDK) not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sqs, aws-cdk, amazon-kms

I have an architecture developed with CDK with a S3 bucket and an event notification which will send a message to a SQS for each uploaded file to S3.

It works fine.

Now I'm trying to activate the encryption and I have the following:

- for S3 -> I have activated the encryption using S3_MANAGED key and everything works fine
- for SQS -> I have activated the encryption using KMS_MANAGED key and there is **no message sent to SQS**.

So I'm assuming some permissions are missing but I don't know how to fix it.

Do I need to add missing permissions to SQS to read from S3? Or permissions to S3 to send messages to a encrypted SQS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TL;DR**  S3 Notifications don't work with `sqs.QueueEncryption.KMS_MANAGED`.  Use a customer-managed key to encrypt the queue.

[AWS Knowledge Base: Why aren’t Amazon S3 event notifications delivered to an Amazon SQS queue that uses server-side encryption?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/sqs-s3-event-notification-sse/):

> The default AWS managed KMS key can't be modified. You must use a customer managed key ... and add permissions to the KMS key to allow access to a specified service principal.

Here's a minimal working example:

```js
// S3 Notifications to a Encrypted Queue
export class S3SqsStack extends cdk.Stack {
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props: cdk.StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    const bucket = new s3.Bucket(this, 'MyBucket', {
      encryption: s3.BucketEncryption.S3_MANAGED,
    });

    // https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/sqs-s3-event-notification-sse/
    const key = new kms.Key(this, 'MyCustomerKey', {
      policy: new iam.PolicyDocument({
        statements: [
          new iam.PolicyStatement({
            actions: ['kms:GenerateDataKey', 'kms:Decrypt'],
            resources: ['*'], // avoid circularity by not limiting the resource
            principals: [new iam.ServicePrincipal('s3.amazonaws.com')],
          }),
        ],
      }),
    });

    const queue = new sqs.Queue(this, 'MyQueue', {
      encryption: sqs.QueueEncryption.KMS,
      encryptionMasterKey: key,
    });

    bucket.addEventNotification(s3.EventType.OBJECT_CREATED, new s3n.SqsDestination(queue));
  }
}
```